# protobuf-net: how to serialize an EventHandler

Tags: c#, serialization, protobuf-net

I am attempting to serialize a class with a EventHandler using protobuf-net, using the following code:

```
    [ProtoContract]
    class Thing
    {
        [ProtoMember(5, AsReference = true)]
        public EventHandler _DoSomething;

        public event EventHandler DoSomething
        {
            add { _DoSomething += value; }
            remove { _DoSomething -= value; }
        }

        public void PerformSomething(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
        }
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void SerializingAClassWithAnEvent_Deserializes()
    {
        var Guy1 = new Thing() {};
        var Guy2 = new Thing() {};
        Guy2.DoSomething += Guy1.PerformSomething;
        Assert.IsNotNull(Guy2._DoSomething);

        MemoryStream buffer = new MemoryStream();
        Serializer.Serialize(buffer, Guy2);
        MemoryStream afterStream = new MemoryStream(buffer.ToArray());
        var outGuy = Serializer.Deserialize<Thing>(afterStream);

        Assert.IsNotNull(outGuy._DoSomething);
    }
```

This code compiles and runs fine but the second assertion fails because the _DoSomething EventHandler is still null. What am I missing?

Comment: AFAIK EventHandlers can't be serialised. It's null because there are no handlers attached to the new instance.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Will Hughes is right in his comment.

Comment: I can confirm (as the library author) that MBen's answer is correct. Delegates are simply not supported or supportable. Basically, that only really makes sense for remoting / BinaryFormatter. Most serializers (XmlSerializer, DataContractSerializer, JSON.NET, protobuf-net, etc) do not support delegates.

Answer (score 4):

From the documentation [here](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/wiki/GettingStarted) EventHandlers are not supported

```
custom classes that:
   are marked as data-contract;
   have a parameterless constructor;
   for Silverlight: are public
many common primitives etc
single dimension arrays: T[]
List<T> / IList<T>
Dictionary<TKey,TValue> / IDictionary<TKey,TValue>
any type which implements IEnumerable<T> and has an Add(T) method
```